# probability of a number divisible by 2 and 3

Tags: probability

Three distinct numbers are selected from first hundred natural numbers , then we have to find the probability of selected numbers divisible by both 2 and 3.

Not getting any start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural number is divisible by $2$ or $3$, if it is divisible by $6$.
So, numbers divisible by $6$ are {$6,12,18, . . . . ,96$}.
So there are total $16$ numbers out of which $3$ distinct number can be chosen in $16×15×14=n(A)$. Also,the total no of ways = $100×99×98=n(S)$.

Required probability=$\frac{n(A)}{n(S)} = \frac{4}{1155}$. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to calculate the probability of selecting a number and being divisible by 2 and 3. For that you have to count how many numbers are divisible by 2 and 3 between the first hundred numbers, I call it $n_{2,3}$ and divide it by 100. (Laplace's Rule).
As you have three distinct numbers, you have to calculate the first probability that is $n_{2,3}/100$, the second is $(n_{2,3}-1)/99$ and the third is $(n_{2,3}-2)/98$ because there are three distinct numbers you have to it sustrating it.
And only you have to multiply the three probabilities because they are independent.

Comment: Answer is 4/1155

Answer (score 0):

The way you have posed the question it seems the numbers are chosen together. 
If however the number were chosen one after one with replacement the events in that case would've been independent.
Suppose there are ***k*** numbers between 1 to 100 which are divisible by both 2 and 3 or in other words a factor of 6. It is trivial to find the value of ***k***.

The number of ways in which you can choose these 3 numbers are ***k*(k-1)*(k-2)***.
Similarly the total outcomes are 100*99*98.
Calculation of probability is straightforward.

Comment: Answer is 4/1155